# How to schedule a service to run daily and at specific time using service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I am trying to build a service in such away that it runs once a day at a specific time to minimize multiple calls to the database using service fabric

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Actor reminders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders#actor-reminders)

You need to call RegisterReminderAsync. To run every 24 hours

```
var reminderRegistration = await this.RegisterReminderAsync(
        reminderName,
        BitConverter.GetBytes(amountInDollars),
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),    //The amount of time to delay before firing the reminder
        TimeSpan.FromHours(24));    //The time interval between firing of reminders
```

If you want to run at a specific time, you can trigger every hour/ x minutes and in the method you can check if DateTime.UtcNow is in the correct window.

Comment: Would there not be a possibility that it would miss the correct time depending on the interval used e.g if it runs every 5 minutes and the DateTime let say 00:01 is when it should run and its triggered at 00:00?

Comment: You could keep the last execution date in the reminder state to counter this.